# ALTER COLUMN on table with access lock

Tags: postgresql

I'm trying to alter a table column in Postgres, but the table has several AccessShare and AccessExclusive locks. How do I over come the locks?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Kick out the connections that cause the locks. Use pg_cancel_backend() or even pg_terminate_backend().

http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-admin.html

Comment: Yikes, there are 18 related to that table in question!